# How to Split Image Into Multiple Pieces in Python

Tags: python, image, split, python-imaging-library, crop

I'm trying to split a photo into multiple pieces using PIL.

```
def crop(Path,input,height,width,i,k,x,y,page):
    im = Image.open(input)
    imgwidth = im.size[0]
    imgheight = im.size[1]
    for i in range(0,imgheight-height/2,height-2):
        print i
        for j in range(0,imgwidth-width/2,width-2):
            print j
            box = (j, i, j+width, i+height)
            a = im.crop(box)
            a.save(os.path.join(Path,"PNG","%s" % page,"IMG-%s.png" % k))
            k +=1
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. It splits the photo but not in an exact way (you can try it).

Comment: What do you mean by "exact" width and height?

Comment: Using [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/index.html#user) library: `tiles = [im[x:x+M,y:y+N] for x in range(0,im.shape[0],M) for y in range(0,im.shape[1],N)]` - See my answer below

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

def crop(path, input, height, width, k, page, area):
    im = Image.open(input)
    imgwidth, imgheight = im.size
    for i in range(0,imgheight,height):
        for j in range(0,imgwidth,width):
            box = (j, i, j+width, i+height)
            a = im.crop(box)
            try:
                o = a.crop(area)
                o.save(os.path.join(path,"PNG","%s" % page,"IMG-%s.png" % k))
            except:
                pass
            k +=1
```

Comment: Why is `k` a parameter of this function? Shouldn't it always be `0` when calling the function? Also what is `area`? Why do you `crop` the image twice?

Comment: What do all your arguments mean?

Comment: arguments are quiet obvious if you read the code and k is the offset

Answer (score 51):

Splitting image to tiles of MxN pixels (assuming im is numpy.ndarray):

```
tiles = [im[x:x+M,y:y+N] for x in range(0,im.shape[0],M) for y in range(0,im.shape[1],N)]
```

In the case you want to split the image to four pieces:

```
M = im.shape[0]//2
N = im.shape[1]//2
```

tiles[0] holds the upper left tile

Comment: For my case the easiest solution, also isn't calculation expensive

Comment: @DeepPatel you are wrong.  The resulting tiles do not overshoot the image size for any values of N and M, since slicing the image beyond its borders ignores the redundant parts. The following statement is correct for any 0<=x<=im.shape[0]: assert im[im.shape[0]-x:im.shape[0]+x:,:].shape[0] == x

Comment: My bad, I was using this for something else and may have made some mistake when modifying it. You are right.

Comment: Any one try putting these back together after splitting?

Comment: @Thomas this is late, but for posterity, the sequence of tiles given by the code goes row by row. So, if you have six tiles with 2 rows and 3 columns, then to put it back together, you do row0=[tiles[0],tiles[1],tiles[2]] and row1=[tiles[3],tiles[4],tiles[5]]

Answer (score 44):

As an alternative solution, we will construct the tiles by generating a grid of coordinates using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). We will ignore partial tiles on the edges, only iterating through the cartesian product between the two intervals, *i.e.* `range(0, h-h%d, d) X range(0, w-w%d, d)`.

Given `filename`: the image file name, `d`: the tile size, `dir_in`: the path to the directory containing the image, and `dir_out`: the directory where tiles will be outputted:

```py
from PIL import Image
from itertools import product
```

```py
def tile(filename, dir_in, dir_out, d):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(dir_in, filename))
    w, h = img.size
    
    grid = product(range(0, h-h%d, d), range(0, w-w%d, d))
    for i, j in grid:
        box = (j, i, j+d, i+d)
        out = os.path.join(dir_out, f'{name}_{i}_{j}{ext}')
        img.crop(box).save(out)
```

[image]

Comment: Very practical solution, thanks. It might be useful to send 'fp' as an argument to the function because 'filename' and 'fp' variables can be confusing.

Comment: Thank you @Kubra. I was using `fp` in my source code it seems, I have changed it to the correct argument naming.

Comment: Really needed this solution

Comment: Really clean, easy to understand.

Comment: Using this method with a VERY large image I seem to get "Too many open files", any idea why it might be happening?

Answer (score 43):

Edit: I believe this answer missed the intent to cut an image into rectangles in columns and rows. This answer cuts only into rows. It looks like other answers cut in columns and rows.

Simpler than all these is to use a wheel someone else invented :) It may be more involved to set up, but then it's a snap to use.

These instructions are for Windows 7; they may need to be adapted for other OSs.

Get and install pip from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html).

Download the install archive, and extract it to your root Python installation directory. Open a console and type (if I recall correctly):

```
python get-pip.py install
```

Then get and install the image_slicer module via pip, by entering the following command at the console:

```
python -m pip install image_slicer
```

Copy the image you want to slice into the Python root directory, open a python shell (not the "command line"), and enter these commands:

```
import image_slicer
image_slicer.slice('huge_test_image.png', 14)
```

The beauty of this module is that it

1. Is installed in python
2. Can invoke an image split with two lines of code
3. Accepts any even number as an image slice parameter (e.g. 14 in this example)
4. Takes that parameter and automagically splits the given image into so many slices, and auto-saves the resultant numbered tiles in the same directory, and finally
5. Has a function to stitch the image tiles back together (which I haven't yet tested); files apparently must be named after the convention which you will see in the split files after testing the image_slicer.slice function.

Comment: it looks good, but its documentation is poor. It also gives good control over tiles once they are created but it is not easy to see how the image will be sliced. I was expecting a kind of tuple to set number of rows and columns

Comment: Per comments on other answers, no this is probably not an option on memory-constrained systems.

Comment: \get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @user7082181 try another method of installing pip as documented (at this writing) here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/

Answer (score 21):

1. `crop` would be a more reusable
   function if you separate the
   cropping code from the
   image saving
   code. It would also make the call
   signature simpler.
2. `im.crop` returns a
   `Image._ImageCrop` instance. Such
   instances do not have a save method.
   Instead, you must paste the
   `Image._ImageCrop` instance onto a
   new `Image.Image`
3. Your ranges do not have the right
   step sizes. (Why `height-2` and not
   `height`? for example. Why stop at
   `imgheight-(height/2)`?).

So, you might try instead something like this:

```
import Image
import os

def crop(infile,height,width):
    im = Image.open(infile)
    imgwidth, imgheight = im.size
    for i in range(imgheight//height):
        for j in range(imgwidth//width):
            box = (j*width, i*height, (j+1)*width, (i+1)*height)
            yield im.crop(box)

if __name__=='__main__':
    infile=...
    height=...
    width=...
    start_num=...
    for k,piece in enumerate(crop(infile,height,width),start_num):
        img=Image.new('RGB', (height,width), 255)
        img.paste(piece)
        path=os.path.join('/tmp',"IMG-%s.png" % k)
        img.save(path)
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but it doesn't work with me, the picture has been not cropped good, i see red color, i think the problem maybe here : `img.paste(piece)`

Comment: This is an especially nice solution if you have memory constraints.  Large images may fail on machines with low memory when using image_slicer.

Comment: The behavior that @Elteroooo is getting is because the code has an error, on line 18: `img=Image.new('RGB', (height,width), 255)`, `width` and `height` should have been switched. I suggested an edit but it was rejected ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4):

Here is a concise, pure-python solution that works in both python 3 and 2:

```
from PIL import Image

infile = '20190206-135938.1273.Easy8thRunnersHopefully.jpg'
chopsize = 300

img = Image.open(infile)
width, height = img.size

# Save Chops of original image
for x0 in range(0, width, chopsize):
   for y0 in range(0, height, chopsize):
      box = (x0, y0,
             x0+chopsize if x0+chopsize <  width else  width - 1,
             y0+chopsize if y0+chopsize < height else height - 1)
      print('%s %s' % (infile, box))
      img.crop(box).save('zchop.%s.x%03d.y%03d.jpg' % (infile.replace('.jpg',''), x0, y0))
```

Notes:

The crops that go over the right and bottom of the original image are adjusted to the original image limit and contain only the original pixels.

It's easy to choose a different chopsize for w and h by using two chopsize vars and replacing chopsize as appropriate in the code above.

Comment: only works for pngs and doesn't work for files in directories, but this was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Worked a treat for me with jpg's.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a late answer that works with Python 3

```
from PIL import Image
import os

def imgcrop(input, xPieces, yPieces):
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(input)
    im = Image.open(input)
    imgwidth, imgheight = im.size
    height = imgheight // yPieces
    width = imgwidth // xPieces
    for i in range(0, yPieces):
        for j in range(0, xPieces):
            box = (j * width, i * height, (j + 1) * width, (i + 1) * height)
            a = im.crop(box)
            try:
                a.save("images/" + filename + "-" + str(i) + "-" + str(j) + file_extension)
            except:
                pass
```

Usage:

```
imgcrop("images/testing.jpg", 5, 5)
```

Then the images will be cropped into pieces according to the specified X and Y pieces, in my case 5 x 5 = 25 pieces

Answer (score 3):

I find it easier to `skimage.util.view_as_windows` or `skimage.util.view_as_blocks which also allows you to configure the step

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html?highlight=view_as_windows#skimage.util.view_as_windows

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the most efficient answer, but it works for me:

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None # to avoid image size warning

imgdir = "/path/to/image/folder"
# if you want file of a specific extension (.png):
filelist = [f for f in glob.glob(imgdir + "**/*.png", recursive=True)]
savedir = "/path/to/image/folder/output"

start_pos = start_x, start_y = (0, 0)
cropped_image_size = w, h = (500, 500)

for file in filelist:
    img = Image.open(file)
    width, height = img.size

    frame_num = 1
    for col_i in range(0, width, w):
        for row_i in range(0, height, h):
            crop = img.crop((col_i, row_i, col_i + w, row_i + h))
            name = os.path.basename(file)
            name = os.path.splitext(name)[0]
            save_to= os.path.join(savedir, name+"_{:03}.png")
            crop.save(save_to.format(frame_num))
            frame_num += 1
```

This is mostly based on DataScienceGuy answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501331/crop-entire-image-with-the-same-cropping-size-with-pil-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution, just using NumPy built-in `np.array_split` :

```
def divide_img_blocks(img, n_blocks=(5, 5)):
    horizontal = np.array_split(img, n_blocks[0])
    splitted_img = [np.array_split(block, n_blocks[1], axis=1) for block in horizontal]
    return np.asarray(splitted_img, dtype=np.ndarray).reshape(n_blocks)
```

It returns a NumPy array with the dimension passed as n_blocks.
Each element of the array is a block, so to access each block and save it as an image you should write something like the following:

```
result = divide_img_blocks(my_image)

for i in range(result.shape[0]):
    for j in range(result.shape[1]):
        cv2.imwrite(f"my_block_{i}_{j}.jpg", result[i,j])
```

This answer is very fast, faster than @Nir answer, which among the posted ones was the cleanest. Additionally is almost three orders of magnitude faster than the suggested package (i.e. `image_slicer`).

```
Time taken by divide_img_blocks: 0.0009832382202148438
Time taken by Nir answer: 0.002960681915283203
Time taken by image_slicer.slice: 0.4419238567352295
```

Hope it can still be useful.

Comment: Does this assume the image is square?  It would be nice if you could update your answer with a test image -- one you know works. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @pookie, the method will take any image size and any number of "blocks".
[Here is a way of testing it](https://pastebin.com/1iNSXJZG).

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
import sys
from PIL import Image

savedir = r"E:\new_mission _data\test"
filename = r"E:\new_mission _data\test\testing1.png"
img = Image.open(filename)
width, height = img.size
start_pos = start_x, start_y = (0, 0)
cropped_image_size = w, h = (1024,1024)

frame_num = 1
for col_i in range(0, width, w):
    for row_i in range(0, height, h):
        crop = img.crop((col_i, row_i, col_i + w, row_i + h))
        save_to= os.path.join(savedir, "testing_{:02}.png")
        crop.save(save_to.format(frame_num))
        frame_num += 1
```

Comment: this code works for me as you can change cropped_image_size at your convinence

Comment: this code can crop a large image into number of small images

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a simple approach to this, here is a simple working function for splitting an image into NxN sections.

```py
def slice_image(filename, N):

    i = Image.open(filename)

    width = i.width
    height = i.height

    for x in range(N):

        for y in range(N):

            index = (x * pieces) + 1 + y

            img = i.crop((x * width/N, y * height/N,
                          x * width/N+ width/N, y * height/N+ height/N))

            img.save(f"{filename}_sliced_{index}.jpeg")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @[Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698752/20531196) for teaching me something about itertools and grids. Came here to split up tomographic 3D image data (tif-files) into smaller regions for evaluation. I adapted the script to 3D-TIF files (using the [tiffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) library) and added a "centered" approach. So the tiles don't start in the upper-left corner but are centered and crop too small tiles at the borders at each direction. Maybe this also help other people.

```
from itertools import product
import tifffile as tif
import numpy as np

path = 'PATH'
filename= 'FILENAME.tif'
img = tif.imread(path+filename)

depth, height, width = img.shape
tilesize = 100

grid = product(range(int((depth%tilesize)/2), int(depth-(depth%tilesize)/2), tilesize),
               range(int((width%tilesize)/2), int(width-((width%tilesize)/2)), tilesize), 
               range(int((height%tilesize)/2), int(height-(height%tilesize)/2), tilesize))

for z,y,x in grid:
    crop = img[z:z+tilesize, y:y+tilesize, x:x+tilesize]
    tif.imwrite(path+filename+f'{z:04d}z_{y:04d}y_{x:04d}x.tif', crop, dtype = np.uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this one today for my tif file.

Answer (score 0):

This is my script tools, it is very sample to splite css-sprit image into icons:

```
Usage: split_icons.py img dst_path width height
Example: python split_icons.py icon-48.png gtliu 48 48
```

Save code into split_icons.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import glob
from PIL import Image

def Usage():
    print '%s img dst_path width height' % (sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

if len(sys.argv) != 5:
    Usage()

src_img = sys.argv[1]
dst_path = sys.argv[2]

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[2]) or not os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]):
    print 'Not exists', sys.argv[2], sys.argv[1]
    sys.exit(1)

w, h = int(sys.argv[3]), int(sys.argv[4])
im = Image.open(src_img)
im_w, im_h = im.size
print 'Image width:%d height:%d  will split into (%d %d) ' % (im_w, im_h, w, h)
w_num, h_num = int(im_w/w), int(im_h/h)

for wi in range(0, w_num):
    for hi in range(0, h_num):
        box = (wi*w, hi*h, (wi+1)*w, (hi+1)*h)
        piece = im.crop(box)
        tmp_img = Image.new('L', (w, h), 255)
        tmp_img.paste(piece)
        img_path = os.path.join(dst_path, "%d_%d.png" % (wi, hi))
        tmp_img.save(img_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions above, but sometimes you just gotta do it yourself.
Might be off by a pixel in some cases but works fine in general.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def image_to_tiles(im, number_of_tiles = 4, plot=False):
    """
    Function that splits SINGLE channel images into tiles
    :param im: image: single channel image (NxN matrix)
    :param number_of_tiles: squared number
    :param plot:
    :return tiles:
    """
    n_slices = np.sqrt(number_of_tiles)
    assert int(n_slices + 0.5) ** 2 == number_of_tiles, "Number of tiles is not a perfect square"

    n_slices = n_slices.astype(np.int)
    [w, h] = cropped_npy.shape

    r = np.linspace(0, w, n_slices+1)
    r_tuples = [(np.int(r[i]), np.int(r[i+1])) for i in range(0, len(r)-1)]
    q = np.linspace(0, h, n_slices+1)
    q_tuples = [(np.int(q[i]), np.int(q[i+1])) for i in range(0, len(q)-1)]

    tiles = []
    for row in range(n_slices):
        for column in range(n_slices):
            [x1, y1, x2, y2] = *r_tuples[row], *q_tuples[column] 
            tiles.append(im[x1:y1, x2:y2])

    if plot:
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_slices, n_slices, figsize=(10,10))
        c = 0
        for row in range(n_slices):
            for column in range(n_slices):
                axes[row,column].imshow(tiles[c])
                axes[row,column].axis('off')
                c+=1

    return tiles
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `NameError: name 'cropped_npy' is not defined`

Comment: yeah sorry, should be [w, h] = im.shape

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use multiprocessing instead of a regular for loop as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

def crop(infile,height,width):
    im = Image.open(infile)
    imgwidth, imgheight = im.size
    for i in range(imgheight//height):
        for j in range(imgwidth//width):
            box = (j*width, i*height, (j+1)*width, (i+1)*height)
            yield im.crop(box)

def til_image(infile):
    infile=...
    height=...
    width=...
    start_num=...
    for k,piece in enumerate(crop(infile,height,width),start_num):
        img=Image.new('RGB', (height,width), 255)
        img.paste(piece)
        path=os.path.join('/tmp',"IMG-%s.png" % k)
        img.save(path)

from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
try:
    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    pool.imap_unordered(tile_image, os.listdir(root), chunksize=4)
finally:
    pool.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way:

```
import image_slicer
image_slicer.slice('/Address of image for exp/A1.png',16)
```

this command splits the image into 16 slices and saves them in the directory that the input image is there.
you should first install image_slicer:

```
pip install image_slicer
```

Answer (score 0):

**Splitting an image into squares of a specific size**

I adapted a solution so that it accepts a specific tile size instead of an amount of tiles because I needed to cut the image up into a grid of 32px squares.

The parameters are the `image_path` and the `size of the tile`s in pixels.

I tried to make the code as readable as possible.

```py
# Imports
from PIL import Image
import os
import random

# Function
def image_to_tiles(im, tile_size = 32):
    """
    Function that splits an image into tiles
    :param im: image: image path
    :param tile_size: width in pixels of a tile
    :return tiles:
    """
    image = Image.open(im)
        
    w = image.width
    h = image.height
    
    row_count = np.int64((h-h%tile_size)/tile_size)
    col_count = np.int64((w-w%tile_size)/tile_size)
    
    n_slices = np.int64(row_count*col_count)
    
    # Image info
    print(f'Image: {im}')
    print(f'Dimensions: w:{w} h:{h}')
    print(f'Tile count: {n_slices}')


    r = np.linspace(0, w, row_count+1)
    r_tuples = [(np.int64(r[i]), np.int64(r[i])+tile_size) for i in range(0, len(r)-1)]
    q = np.linspace(0, h, col_count+1)
    q_tuples = [(np.int64(q[i]), np.int64(q[i])+tile_size) for i in range(0, len(q)-1)]
    
    #print(f'r_tuples:{r_tuples}\n\nq_tuples:{q_tuples}\n')
    
    tiles = []
    for row in range(row_count):
        for column in range(col_count):
            [y1, y2, x1, x2] = *r_tuples[row], *q_tuples[column]
            x2 = x1+tile_size
            y2 = y1+tile_size
            tile_image = image.crop((x1,y1,x2,y2))
            tile_coords = {'x1':x1,'y1':y1,'x2':x2,'y2':y2}
            tiles.append({'image':tile_image,'coords':tile_coords})

    return tiles

# Testing:
img_path ='/home/user/path/to/image.jpg'
tiles = image_to_tiles(img_path)

for i in range(20):
    tile = random.choice(tiles)
    tile['image'].show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def split(img,nbxsplit,nbysplit):
      xdemi=int(img.shape[0]/nbxsplit)
      ydemi=int(img.shape[1]/nbxsplit)
      arr=[]
      for i in range(0,img.shape[0]-xdemi+1,xdemi):
                 for j in range(0,img.shape[1]-ydemi+1,ydemi):
                          arr.append(img[i:i+xdemi][j:j+ydemi])
      a=np.reshape(a,(img.shape[0]-xdemi,img.shape[1]-xdemi))
      return a
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy stride tricks to achive this, but be careful, as `this function has to be used with extreme care` ([doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html))

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def img_pieces(img, piece_size):
    height, width, chanels = img.shape
    n_bytes = img.strides[-1]

    return np.reshape(
        as_strided(
            img,
            (
                height // piece_size,
                width // piece_size,
                piece_size,
                piece_size,
                chanels
            ),
            (
                n_bytes * chanels * width * piece_size,
                n_bytes * chanels * piece_size,
                n_bytes * chanels * width,
                n_bytes * chanels,
                n_bytes
            )
        ),
        (
            -1,
            piece_size,
            piece_size,
            chanels
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt on a grayscale image with only numpy based on the solution from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/efficiently-splitting-an-image-into-tiles-in-python-using-numpy-d1bf0dd7b6f7), with some minor tweaks (adding channels) it might suit your needs:

```
import numpy as np

# Seperate grayscale images to w * h tiles, add padding with zeros if image not scaled
def to_tiles(arr: np.ndarray, tilesize: tuple[int, int]) -> np.ndarray:
    def f(x: tuple[int, int]) -> tuple[int, int]:
        tmp = list(x)
        if tmp[1] > 0:
            tmp[0] = tmp[0] + 1
        return tuple(tmp)

    # # Stride Implementation
    # bytelength = np.int8(np.divide(arr.nbytes, arr.size))

    assert arr.ndim == 2, "array must be 2d (grayscale) image"
    a_h, a_w = arr.shape
    h, w = tilesize
    assert a_h > h, "tile height is larger than arr height"
    assert a_w > w, "tile width is larger than arr width"
    row, row_r = f(np.divmod(a_h, h))
    col, col_r = f(np.divmod(a_w, w))
    
    arr = np.pad(
        arr,
        [
            (
                np.int8(np.ceil(np.divide(h-row_r, 2))) if row_r != 0 else 0,
                np.int8(np.floor(np.divide(h-row_r, 2))) if row_r != 0 else 0,
            ),
            (
                np.int8(np.ceil(np.divide(w-col_r, 2))) if col_r != 0 else 0,
                np.int8(np.floor(np.divide(w-col_r, 2))) if col_r != 0 else 0,
            ),
        ],
        "constant",
        constant_values=(0),
    )

    # # Stride Implementation
    # arr = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
    #     arr, shape=(row, col, h, w), strides=(h*a_w*bytelength, w*bytelength, a_w*bytelength, bytelength)
    # )

    arr = arr.reshape(row, h, col, w).swapaxes(1, 2)
    arr = arr.reshape(-1, h, w)

    return arr
```

[Here's an example of the result. Image from FUNSD dataset.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3wNH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's still relevant, but my attempt is following:
(I am assuming the image is a numpy array. I am not using Pil or anything, since i didn't want to have any dependencies other than numpy.)

```
def cut_image_grid(image:np.ndarray, grid_size:int=4):
     height, width = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]
     piece_height, piece_width = height//grid_size, width//grid_size
     pieces = []
     for i in range(grid_size):
          for j in range(grid_size):
               y = i * piece_height
               x = j * piece_width
               h = (i+1) * piece_height if i < grid_size else None
               w = (j+1) * piece_width if j < grid_size else None
               piece = image[y:h, x:w]
               pieces.append(piece)
     return np.array(pieces)
```

As input the function is receiving a numpy image and an integer (which you could also turn into tuples, but i wanted to have evenly spaced grid cells always with same amount of cells row and column wise).
At first, the code calculates the width and height of the cells based on the given `grid_size`. After that the code iterates over all rows and columns and generates x, y Coordinates, as well as x0 and y0 (y+height, x+width) for defining the cells.
Every cell is saved as a list into `pieces`, which is then transformed into a numpy array and returned.

Answer (score -1):

```
import cv2

def crop_image(image_path, output_path):
    im =  cv2.imread(os.listdir()[2])
    imgheight=im.shape[0]
    imgwidth=im.shape[1]

    y1 = 0
    M = 2000
    N = 2000
    for y in range(0,imgheight,M):
        for x in range(0, imgwidth, N):
            y1 = y + M
            x1 = x + N
            tiles = im[y:y+M,x:x+N]
            if tiles.shape[0] < 100 or  tiles.shape[1]<100:
                continue

            cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0))
            cv2.imwrite(output_path +  str(x) + '_' + str(y)+"{}.png".format(image_path),tiles)
crop_image(os.listdir()[2], './cutted/')
```