# What javascript framework is google images using for pinch zoom?

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, google-search, pinchzoom

Google has now implemented a very unique pinch zoom for their images. The viewport meta tag does not allow user scaling or zooming, and as you would expect the resulting content is not pinch-zoomable on a mobile touch device. The image, however, is pinch zoomable. The image is the only part of the page that zooms, and the viewport scaling never changes. Does anyone know what javascript framework they are using to accomplish this? Is it publicly available?

Comment: I doubt that it is publicly available.

Comment: did you see this? --> [Using Google Maps Javascript API pinch-to-zoom on my own image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207481/using-google-maps-javascript-api-pinch-to-zoom-on-my-own-image)

Comment: No I haven't, very nice. I wonder if that's what they are using. Their image allows some kind of vertical swipe detection, which allows the page to scroll, which is important. I'm not too sure the map framework would be capable of this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think their version is opensource, however this library is pretty nice:

https://openseadragon.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what google uses but there is a jQuery library that does this. It's called
[panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom)