# How do you divide an image/array into blocks?

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering is it possible to divide image into blocks for example 8x8 blocks (`64 pixels per block`) and perform histogram function for each block and save results into a new image not to separately images?

```
def apply_histogram(block):
    h, b = np.histogram(block.flatten(), 256, normed=True)
    cdf = h.cumsum()
    cdf = 255 * cdf / cdf[-1]
    return np.interp(block.flatten(), b[:-1], cdf).reshape(block.shape)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Split Image Into Multiple Pieces in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953373/how-to-split-image-into-multiple-pieces-in-python)

Comment: I do not want to split image. And I do not want to apply function to image at once, I want to apply function in image to every 8x8 block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not loop through all `8x8` blocks in the image?

```
image = ...
block_img = np.zeros(image.shape)
im_h, im_w = image.shape[:2]
bl_h, bl_w = 8, 8

for row in np.arange(im_h - bl_h + 1, step=bl_h):
    for col in np.arange(im_w - bl_w + 1, step=bl_w):
        block_img[row:row+bl_h, col:col+bl_w] = apply_histogram(image[row:row+bl_h, col:col+bl_w])
```

`image`:

[image: Cameraman image]

`block_img`:

[image: Histogram applied to blocks]