# Splitting a large file by size into smaller chunks

Tags: python-3.x, file, split

is there a way to split a given file whether a text file or image file into smaller chunks of equal size and reassemble them again in python ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you mean something like [How to Split Image Into Multiple Pieces in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5953373/9110128)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Split Image Into Multiple Pieces in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953373/how-to-split-image-into-multiple-pieces-in-python)

Comment: No i have to be able to split both types in the same way i am not sure how though