# Split picture into 6 picture with removing spaces

Tags: image, crop, trim

I have some cards which are in a big pictures and I want to split the picture into 6 . In Python I prefer[image: The pictures]

At the end I wanted to have 6 pictures with each one has one card .

Comment: In what language? You can use gimp for doing that (and more)... https://www.gimp.org/

Comment: Python would be perfect . I dont know how to use Gimp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Split Image Into Multiple Pieces in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953373/how-to-split-image-into-multiple-pieces-in-python)

Comment: Not exactly and the first answer is not commented